# Can't access Webadmin in Neo4j Embedded

Tags: neo4j

I'm following the guide on [this](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-embedded.html) page, and it gets the server up and running, but the webadmin doesn't work. And being a newbie to Neo4j, the webadmin is VERY useful to me. When trying to access the webadmin, I just get a 404 Not Found error. And it doesn't seem like the logs are telling me that anything is wrong.

```
May 14, 2013 11:41:33 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
May 14, 2013 11:41:33 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Starting Neo Server on port [7474] with [40] threads available
May 14, 2013 11:41:34 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounted discovery module at [/]
May 14, 2013 11:41:34 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Loaded server plugin "CypherPlugin"
May 14, 2013 11:41:34 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounted REST API at [/db/data]
May 14, 2013 11:41:34 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounted management API at [/db/manage]
May 14, 2013 11:41:34 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounted webadmin at [/webadmin]
11:41:34.598 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Logging to Logger[org.mortbay.log] via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
May 14, 2013 11:41:34 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Mounting static content at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
May 14, 2013 11:41:34 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: No static content available for Neo Server at port [7474], management console may not be available.
11:41:34.651 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log - jetty-6.1.25
May 14, 2013 11:41:34 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rest
May 14, 2013 11:41:34 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rest.console.ConsoleService
  class org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rest.JmxService
  class org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rest.RootService
  class org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rest.MonitorService
May 14, 2013 11:41:34 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
May 14, 2013 11:41:34 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
May 14, 2013 11:41:35 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.neo4j.server.rest.web
May 14, 2013 11:41:35 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService
  class org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService
  class org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ResourcesService
  class org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService
  class org.neo4j.server.rest.web.RestfulGraphDatabase
  class org.neo4j.server.rest.web.DatabaseMetadataService
May 14, 2013 11:41:35 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
May 14, 2013 11:41:35 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
May 14, 2013 11:41:35 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.neo4j.server.rest.discovery
May 14, 2013 11:41:35 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class org.neo4j.server.rest.discovery.DiscoveryService
May 14, 2013 11:41:35 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
May 14, 2013 11:41:35 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
May 14, 2013 11:41:35 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
11:41:35.522 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Started SelectChannelConnector@localhost:7474
INFO: Server started on [http://localhost:7474/]
```

Is there something else I'm supposed to be configuring to get the webadmin working? Do I need to install the Windows service or something?

Comment: Where are you trying to access the webadmin from? By default it will only serve to localhost.

Comment: I'm trying from localhost.

Comment: did you add the ...-static depdencencies?

Comment: How do you try to access it?

Comment: Yes, I added all of the libraries in the system/lib folder as the instructions said. After I did that, I was able to make it run without throwing exceptions, but trying to access the webadmin via Chrome just gave me the 404 error.